# Slovak characters are getting messed up when reading from csv file in java

Tags: java, unicode, inputstream

I am trying to read a comma separated file through InputStream containing some Slovak characters so I am passing proper character encoding in InputStream parameter.
But still characters are getting messed up.

```
InputStreamReader stream = new InputStreamReader(inputStreamToExcel,"ISO-8859-2");
```

For e.g. dd890èš becomes dd890č
Last two Slovak characters got messed up.

Please help.

Comment: How have you decided that the "proper" encoding is ISO-8859-2? What produced the file?

Comment: @Jon Skeet works with `ISO-8859-2` and `ISO8859_2` too ([Windows `cp1250`](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4296969))

Comment: @Infotechie Windows XP pretty to ignore whatever settings in Java (in some cases), you have to get proper charset used for File, I wrote own class for testing ? or squares

Comment: @mKorbel: What do you mean by "works with"? Unless you've got the OP's original file, you can't tell whether ISO-8859-2 is correct *for that file* which is what's important.

Comment: @Jon Skeet accepting both figures `ISO-8859-2` and `ISO8859_2` please see my deleted post here

Comment: @mKorbel: Yes, but that's not what my comment was about at all. Sure, Java supports ISO-8859-2. That doesn't mean it's the "proper" encoding to specify here.

Comment: aaaach your comment has two different meanings (in my first language), agree with that

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I have found from below link the proper encoding for the characters used in the file: http://www.terena.org/activities/multiling/ml-docs/iso-8859.html

Comment: @Infotechie: Do you mean you've seen that the characters you want *occur* in that document? That doesn't mean your file is actually encoded that way. All the characters are *also* in UTF-8. Again: what's producing the file?

Comment: My application is generating itself. I am checking the encoding of file in Notepad++, it is UTF-8 but my application is showing the characters in ANSI format. However, the page encoding is UTF-8 that I can see using firebug in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils escapeHtml(value) resolved the problem. Through escapeHTML I was able to see the exact html entity code that helps me in analyzing that the correct character was read by the application.But when it is assigned to String it is somehow getting converted to wrong format. But when the unescapedHtml string is passed on to view it is properly displayed by the browser because browser understands the HTML entity code properly.

References: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp
            http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html

This is my analysis.If anyone has any points to add on then please add.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of your encoding.
You are creating your InputStreamReader with "ISO-8859-2" encoding.

Try using "UTF-8".Also check what's the encoding of your file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Notepad++ (Encoding->Character Set) or other editors to determine what is encoding of your file. There is nothing wrong with your code. You just have to find right encoding.

Comment: When I am changing Character Set in Notepad++ then no character set is properly dislpaying the character.Characters are properly visible in ANSI encoding only.

Comment: @Infotechie Try to use "ISO8859_2" instead of "ISO-8859-2". See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html